# Get title property in my tabpanel

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

i have a tabpanel in a view and many tabs in tabpanel, i want get the string of title in controller

my tabpanel code:

```
        {
            xtype: 'tabpanel',
            itemId: 'tabfirst',
            flex: 1,
            //activeItem: 1,
            tabBar: {
                layout: {
                    pack: 'center'
                }
            },
            items: [
                {
                    title: 'tab1',//---------i want get it's value tab1
                    xtype: 'list',
                    itemTpl: '{title}',
                    data: [
                        {title : 'title1'},
                        {title : 'title2'},
                        {title : 'title3'}
                    ]
                },
                {
                    title: 'tab2',
                    html: 'here second html2'
                }
            ]
        }
```

in controller launch function code

```
    var moneytab = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('.makemoney #tabfirst')[0];
    console.log(moneytab.getItems().......how can i get the value of title........);
```

the above getItems return a list of array in my chrome console

[image]

my title is in array[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUNqF.jpg) in items.THX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not querying to the tab, but to the tabpanel itself. The items your are showing are the items of the tabpanel, not of the tab..

```
{
    xtype: 'tabpanel',
    itemId: 'myTabPanel',
    flex: 1,
    tabBar: {
        layout: {
            pack: 'center'
        }
    },
    items: [
        {
            title: 'tab1',
            xtype: 'list',
            itemId: 'myFirstTab',
            itemTpl: '{title}',
            data: [
                {title : 'title1'},
                {title : 'title2'},
                {title : 'title3'}
            ]
        },
        {
            title: 'tab2',
            html: 'here second html2'
        }
    ]
}

var tabPanel = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#myTabPanel')[0],
    moneyTab = tabPanel.child('#myFirstTab');

console.log(moneyTab.getTitle());
moneyTab.setTitle('w00t');
console.log(moneyTab.getTitle());
```